# Downloading png from opentopomap.org does not save the png correctly

Tags: python, image, download, multiprocessing, png

My code works fine, but the downloaded pictures can not be opened (they have 1 KB, instead of around 30 KB).

```
import multiprocessing
import pprint
import time
import requests

x1 = int(input("Start i (e.g. 30000):  "))
x2 = int(input("Start j: (e.g. 23000): "))
height = int(input("number of rows: "))
wide = int(input("number columns: "))

urls = [
    f"https://c.tile.opentopomap.org/16/{j}/{i}.png" for i in range(x1, x1 + wide) for j in range(x2, x2 + height)]

def download_image(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(f"Downloading from {url}...")
    url = url.replace("/", "_").replace(":", "_")
    with open(f"{url}", "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter()
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    p.map(download_image, urls)
    p.close()
    stop = time.perf_counter()

    print(f"It took {round(stop - start, 2)} seconds in total")
```

Does anyone see the problem and can provide an answer?

For identifying the location: Go to opentopomap.org -> right click -> View page info -> Media -> Check out the png

PS: In my code I used the second nearest resolution (scale level=16)

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: What happens if you put this address in your web-browser https://c.tile.opentopomap.org/16/23000/30000.png

Comment: haha. this specifically does not work!! https://c.tile.opentopomap.org/16/34746/23081.png try those and it works! perfect.

Comment: Can you you the first 20-30 bytes of your downloaded file in hex, e.g. `xxd image.png` or paste the file into https://hexed.it